# Maven with Eclipse -- point to the proper source file in another project, not binary jar

Tags: eclipse, maven

So I am editing two projects in eclipse at the same time. Both are Maven project.

Let's say project A is version 4.0-SNAPSHOT. B depends on A.

Everytime when I use "Go to declaration" by pressing F3 on a class that's defined in project A, but being used in project B, it always takes me to the read-only binary file in A-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, not the actual source file in project A that I can freely edit.

How do I fix that in Eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems an Eclipse configuration problem...

But you can try to fix this adding sources files into your .m2 local repository..

You can do this just installing the jars in this way..

```
mvn source:jar install
```

It will install the sources jar file..

Eclipse after should be able to get the sources from the m2 repo..